# Document Expired while the use of back link in browser

Tags: php, sql, session

I am building an online database management system and have used sessions to arrange the login and logout part and it is working fine.But the pages linked with database are showing some errors after performing SQL queries.

If I use a navigation bar to go from one page to another, and return to the previous page using the backlink from the browser, it works properly. If I did any SQL work (insertion or searching of data) in that previous page, while going back from next page to this previous page it shows an error "DOCUMENT EXPIRED". If I use the back link twice, I am able to reach that page.

Here is the session code I am implementing:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['user']= $_POST["user"];
session_destroy();
?>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: This is probably due to [*session.cache\_expire*](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cache-expire).

Comment: When you hit the back key, `$_POST` is empty, this is why its not working. You are also setting the session and then just destroying it, so I am not sure what is the point of this code because it does nothing.

Comment: Please guide to solve it

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You're setting a session value and immediately destroying it.

Comment: It's normal behavior. That is because you're using a POST method. Using GET would not have that effect (could be unsafe to use in certain instances), however using Ajax would be better if you're looking for another method. @AM26

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Because its a `POST`-request, the client needs to send the data again (nothing to do with sessions or PHP). There's no direct solution for that. What you can do, is offer the client a link back to the original page, so they don't have to use the `back` button.